# Android background process keep alive

Tags: android, process

I have an android application. This application can open document like PDF from other application.

We have some problem, android system have background process limit and kill process automatically.
It is possible to forbit to android to kill process for our application ? (android can kill pdf-viewer but it's all) .

It is possible ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

See `startForground` in the [service api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). As long as you provide an ongoing notification your service will stick around. (minus times when it'll get killed for low memory or errors)